# Toggle document expansion in Swagger/Swashbuckle

Tags: swagger, swagger-ui, swashbuckle, swashbuckle.aspnetcore

To configure whether the Swagger sections are initially collapsed or not, I can use `SwaggerUIOptions.DocExpansion`. But is it possible to add a link or button to the page that expands or collapses all sections?

Previously, it was possible to add a query parameter `docExpansion={expansion mode}` to the URL (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54998927/689923)). But this does not seem to work anymore.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Previously, it was possible to add a query parameter `docExpansion={expansion mode}` to the URL (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54998927/689923)). But this does not seem to work anymore.

Swagger UI v. 4.1.3+ ignores its query parameters by default for [security reasons](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-ui/issues/4872). To enable query parameter processing, you need to configure Swagger UI with the [`queryConfigEnabled: true`](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-ui/blob/master/docs/usage/configuration.md#user-content-queryconfigenabled) option.

In Swashbuckle.AspNetCore, you can configure this option [as suggested here](https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle.AspNetCore/issues/2516#issuecomment-1313731889):

```cs
app.UseSwaggerUI(c =>
{
    ...
    c.ConfigObject.AdditionalItems["queryConfigEnabled"] = true
}
```